# Index out of bound exception trying to create a window with Swing and JOGL

Tags: java, swing, opengl, awt, jogl

This code is simply supposed to display a window and set its background color:

```
public class Code extends JFrame implements GLEventListener {

    private GLCanvas myCanvas;

    public Code() {
        setTitle("Chapter2 - program1");
        setSize(800, 600);
        setLocation(400, 400);
        myCanvas = new GLCanvas();
        myCanvas.addGLEventListener(this);
        this.add(myCanvas);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
    {  GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
        float[] bkg = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
        FloatBuffer bkgBuffer = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(bkg);
        gl.glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, bkgBuffer);
    }

    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        new Code();
    }

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { }
    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) { }
    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { }
```

The error I get is this one:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 1
    at jogamp.opengl.windows.wgl.awt.WindowsAWTWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory.chooseGraphicsConfigurationImpl(WindowsAWTWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory.java:171)
    at com.jogamp.nativewindow.GraphicsConfigurationFactory.chooseGraphicsConfiguration(GraphicsConfigurationFactory.java:424)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.chooseGraphicsConfiguration(GLCanvas.java:1560)
    at com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas.addNotify(GLCanvas.java:611)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4839)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4839)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4839)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JRootPane.addNotify(JRootPane.java:729)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2804)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.addNotify(Window.java:791)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.addNotify(Frame.java:495)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.show(Window.java:1053)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1728)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1675)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1036)
    at Code.<init>(Code.java:19)
    at Code.main(Code.java:30)
```

I'm using java 8 and sdk 17.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. I changed my OpenJDK version to 11. And it just worked and I don't know why. I don't know at which exact version the error appears, versions prior to 11 seems to work.

**Edit**
It is supposedly fixed in the latest release of JOGL, so you might want to update the .jar

Answer (score 0):

Found this: https://forum.jogamp.org/Crash-in-WindowsAWTWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory-td4040703.html

> > Source from
> > https://github.com/JogAmp/jogl/blob/master/src/jogl/classes/jogamp/opengl/windows/wgl/awt/WindowsAWTWGLGraphicsConfigurationFactory.java
>
> Sourcecode:
> 170:               if( 0 > gcIdx ) {
> 171:                    chosenGC = configs[gcIdx];
> Using a negative index on an
> array will always crash.

Looks like you are also using a negative index.

Comment: In the comment section of your link they're talking about adding "-m" option to java command. This problem might come from the version of OpenJDK. I'm going to test that.

Comment: I tried and it and doesn't work with command line like so (adding -m argument isn't the solution):
**C:\Users\mchulotte\.jdks\openjdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=60146:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\ItelliJ Java\out\production\Basic Canva;C:\JOGL\graphicslib3D.jar;C:\JOGL\jogamp-all-platforms\jar\gluegen-rt.jar;C:\JOGL\jogamp-all-platforms\jar\jogl-all.jar" Code -m**

Comment: I see you fixed the issue by upgrading java. Don't forget to mark your answer as the answer.

Comment: It was fixed in the latest release candidate of JOGL 2.4.0: https://jogamp.org/deployment/v2.4.0-rc-20210111/

Comment: I have the same issue. I think they have solved this issue in Linux but not in Windows.